# node.js res.json messed up

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

first i make a '/init' request and the response is `{"x":50}`,
then i make a '/user' request and the response is `{"x":50,"data":"jack"}`. No problem so far, but if i make an init request again it makes a `{"x":50,"data":"jack"}` response again, how is this possible?

```
    var resp.success = {"x":50} 

    exports.init = function (req, res) {
        res.json(resp.success)
    };

    exports.user = function (req, res) {
        User.findOne({_id: "1234"}).exec(function (err, user) {
            var response = resp.success;
            response.data = user.name;
            res.json(response);
        });
    };
```

Comment: `var response = resp.success` does not make a new copy of resp.success, just a new reference to the original, so when you modify response, you also modify the original. You will need to clone the success message.

Answer (score 2):

Because you've defined var resp.success = {"x":50} in a scope outside the @init and @user methods, when you modify/read the resp.success from within those methods, they are accessing a single shared object instance of resp.success.  You can fix this by defining resp.success independently inside the @init method and @user:

```
exports.init = function (req, res) { 
    var resp.success = {"x":50} 
    res.json(resp.success)
};

exports.user = function (req, res) {
    var resp.success = {"x":50} 
    User.findOne({_id: "1234"}).exec(function (err, user) {
        var response = resp.success;
        response.data = user.name;
        res.json(response);
    });
};
```

If you use the underscoreJS library, you could also do something like this:

```
var resp.success = {"x":50} 
exports.init = function (req, res) { 
    var successResponseForThisRequest = _.clone(res.success);
    res.json(resp.success)
};

exports.user = function (req, res) {
    User.findOne({_id: "1234"}).exec(function (err, user) {
        var successResponseForThisRequest = _.clone(res.success);
        response.data = user.name;
        res.json(response);
    });
};
```